# to run first cgi-python in ubuntu, for a hello world program, it returns " 404 error

Tags: python, cgi

When I tried to run first cgi-python in ubuntu, for a hello world program, it returns " Error code 404.  Message: File not found.  Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI." in browser. I have also started CGIHTTPServer. Whichever browser I tried,it returns same result. I tried saving the python file hello.py both in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.py and also /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.py, but didnt get the output.

Comment: make sure the script file has execute permissions set. You need to enable the file to be executed.

Comment: yes ..using the following command  it has set the execute permission..... sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.py

Comment: even I gave this command also:-  chmod o+x hello.py

Comment: even may I know where is httpd.conf file in ubuntu Apache2 ?because I want to follow the below steps.                                                                                       Register your python file with httpd.conf as a cgi handler by adding the following line:(into the httpd.conf)
AddHandler .py